# Rails 4.0.0, Device 3.0.0.rc :: can't mass-assign protected attributes

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4

Upgrading from Rails 3.2.13 on Ruby 1.9.3 to Rails 4.0.0.

Devise 3.0.0.rc will not mass-assign. I followed all suggestions I found, starting with both approaches describe here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters.

Login/logout works, but registration doesn't:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-03 21:01:47 -0500
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
"authenticity_token"=>"5QPwkbXULEsF5nCiMMK7zd04baZ5kOecgqV2BdRnSEc=", 
"user"=>{"first_name"=>"test", "last_name"=>"testor", "email"=>"asdhd@gmail.com",
"username"=>"testy", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", 
"password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Register"}
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for User: email, password, 
password_confirmation, first_name, last_name, username
```

Is this an issue with Devise? Anybody has a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe do you override devise/registrations_controller in your App?

Comment: Also verify that you remove **attr_accessible** from your **User** model.

Comment: Yes, all that was done, I figured what was the problem, see the answer below.

Comment: Good to hear you fix the issue

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the gem 'protected_attributes' which I used following railscasts http://railscasts.com/episodes/415-upgrading-to-rails-4:

```
...
# add these gems to help with the transition:
gem 'protected_attributes'
...
```

It didn't occur to me the gem would obstruct Rails 4 methods like params.require(:incoming_model).permit( .... ). I might have misunderstood.

Taking the gem out removes the issue. The first approach (the lazy way) mentioned here works: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Set **config.active_record.whitelist_attributes** to false in your **application.rb**.

Add **include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection** to your models

Give a look to: http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/strong-parameters-rails-4-countdown-to-2013

Comment: config.active_record.whitelist_attributes to false in your application.rb. is not an option anymore in R4.

Comment: and strong_parameters gem is part of R4. But I tried it anyway, same result, doesn't work.